# Firestore composite index creation suggestion URLs are incomplete

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

During the development of the application that is using Firestore as the database, I'm coming across the logs as on the screenshot. These URLs are appearing in the browser's developer console or logging service (Sentry in my case)

The problem is, that these URLs are always incomplete (trimmed by the browser's dev console) due to their length.

Is there any other way to find these automatically suggested indexes somewhere else inside the Firebase dashboard?

[image: /v1/r/project/msg-od-qa/firestore/indexes]

Comment: Have you tried with another browser ?

Comment: If there is a single index that you need, create it manually in the Firebase console.

Comment: @AlexMamo It's a composite index, and I'm not sure what exactly it suggests.

Comment: @cicciosgamino the problem is, that it rarely appears in the developer console. I'm getting this logs using Sentry logger

Comment: @TuralAli It suggests creating an index. If you don't know how to create it, please edit your question and show us the query that requires such an index.

Comment: @AlexMamo as far as I know, suggests creating an exact index and when you click on the complete link, it opens the index creation form with prefilled data. but when I click, it just opens indexes overview window

Comment: Please show us the query that requires an index.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're only getting the cut off URLs when they're caught on the device of one of your users and reported to you through Sentry (an error logging tool) which seems to truncate the URL so that it becomes incomplete and doesn't work anymore.

The best options I can think of are:

- Reproduce the error on your development system, and capture the untruncated link in your own logging. This would be what I recommend, as this is the type of error that really should be caught during development.
- Go through all your queries, and ensure you have the necessary index(es) for them in the [Firestore indexes](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/indexes) panel in the Firebase console.